# Leftalign authors with Elsevier class

Tags: horizontal-alignment, elsarticle

I'd like to re-align my title, authors and abstract to the left of the document. I failed with "flushleft". I can use "leftlline" with 'adress', but I dont't know how to leftalign authors. Here's what I have right now:

```
 \documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}
 \journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
 \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
 \graphicspath{{./fig/}}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frontmatter}

 \title{Software XXXX}

 \author[mymainaddress,mysecondaryaddress]{XXX }
 \ead{xxx@cstnet.cn}

 \author[mysecondaryaddress]{XXX\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
 \cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
 \ead{xxx@cnic.cn}

 \author[mymainaddress,mysecondaryaddress]{XXX}
 \ead{xxx@ccc.dd}


 \address[mymainaddress]{\leftline {1600 John F Kennedy Boulevard, Philadel} }
 \address[mysecondaryaddress]{\leftline {360 Park Avenue South, New York}}


 \begin{abstract}
 Increasing network.
 \end{abstract}

 \begin{keyword}
 Software
 \MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
 \end{keyword}

 \end{frontmatter}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this to the preamble to handle both the `preprint` and `final` options:

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{\begin{center}}{\begin{flushleft}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{\end{center}}{\end{flushleft}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\begin{center}}{\begin{flushleft}}{}{}
\patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\end{center}}{\end{flushleft}}{}{}
```

For your example:

```
 \documentclass[5p]{elsarticle}
        \usepackage{etoolbox}
    \patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{\begin{center}}{\begin{flushleft}}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\pprintMaketitle}{\end{center}}{\end{flushleft}}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\begin{center}}{\begin{flushleft}}{}{}
    \patchcmd{\MaketitleBox}{\end{center}}{\end{flushleft}}{}{}

 \journal{Journal of \LaTeX\ Templates}
 \bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}

 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage[ruled,vlined]{algorithm2e}
 \graphicspath{{./fig/}}
 %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

 \begin{document}

 \begin{frontmatter}

 \title{Software XXXX}

 \author[mymainaddress,mysecondaryaddress]{XXX }
 \ead{xxx@cstnet.cn}

 \author[mysecondaryaddress]{XXX\corref{mycorrespondingauthor}}
 \cortext[mycorrespondingauthor]{Corresponding author}
 \ead{xxx@cnic.cn}

 \author[mymainaddress,mysecondaryaddress]{XXX}
 \ead{xxx@ccc.dd}


 \address[mymainaddress]{\leftline {1600 John F Kennedy Boulevard, Philadel} }
 \address[mysecondaryaddress]{\leftline {360 Park Avenue South, New York}}


 \begin{abstract}
 Increasing network.
 \end{abstract}

 \begin{keyword}
 Software
 \MSC[2010] 00-01\sep  99-00
 \end{keyword}

 \end{frontmatter} 
 \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I dit it as what you wrote,it worked immediately.Thank you so much for the helpful answer!